# Best way to encode minimalistic messages

Tags: java, sockets, encoding, message

I need to create a little client/server application that should transfer data like this:

`statistic` <- command type identifier

`15.23.63.12` <- Statistic for this IP address

`increase` <- the kind of action that should be done with the address's statistic

`6` <- Just some other parameters...

So there has to be one string that identifies the type of the command and then there should be some parameters depending on the command type. This parameters are different but always primitive data types. Most probably String, Short, Byte, Integer, and so on...

So there are instruction sets of different primitive data types.

**My question is:** Is it the best way to wrap the socket's streams in DataInput/OutputStreams and just read/write from them? Or is it better to save the messages into a byte array and then wrap this byte array in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and wrap the ByteArrayInputStream in a `DataInputStream` that I can read from? Or should I wrap the byte array in a `ByteBuffer`?

And if I wanted to encrypt my messages, would I have to save them as a byte array, then decrypt the byte array and then wrap it into some kind of data reader?

Comment: A ByteArrayInputStream, as its name indicates, allows reading from a byte array in memory. You won't be able to read anything from the server or client using a ByteArrayInputStream. Obviously, to communicate over a socket, you'll have to read/write from/to the socket streams. I would suggest using JSON to serialize your objects to bytes, or to directly use an ObjectOuntputStream to send Java objects directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this more "efficient" if that's what you're asking.

I would model the command type modifier with bytes, provided that you don't have more than 255 distinct modes:

```
byte cmd_statistic = 0;
byte cmd_nonstatistic = 1;
```

Then each ip address could be modeled as 4 bytes, like this:

```
byte[] ip0 = new byte[]{15, 23, 63, 12};
byte[] ip1 = new byte[]{15, 23, 63, 13};
```

The action could also be bytes:

```
byte action_increase = 0;
byte action_decrease = 1;
```

And if you could model the last parameters as bytes you could get away with just using InputStreams (is) and OutputStreams like this:

```
// Code for reading, writing is very similar
byte cmd = (byte)is.read();

byte[] ip = new byte[4];
is.read(ip, 0, 4);

byte action = (byte)is.read();
byte extra  = (byte)is.read();
```

This is also easy to keep in a large byte[] and that is easier to use for encryption

Comment: Thank you :D That's really a very good way to solve the problem. If I had to store Strings I'd have to use a checksum wouldn't I? And if it is about using Strings is this technique faster than the dataoutputstream? Or could I also use the DataOutputStream?

Comment: If you want to be really efficient i would inspect the content of your strings, and if possible, i would translate each letter to a byte if possible, this way, you can get a byte[] of the same length of your string. Normally each letter in a string is represented by a char, that is 16 bits (2 bytes), but if you don't want to support a lot of different languages and just want to write in 'a' -> 'z', which is only 26 letters, you see that a byte containing 256 different values is even too much. I'm sure you could come up with a good solution with this information :)

Comment: I'll extend DataOutputStream and DataInputStream and add methods to read/write ASCII-Strings, IPv4 addresses and all that stuff.

Comment: If you want to keep it light I would extend InputStream and OutputStream and use the method String getBytes for String to byte[] and just add a sendIp(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2, byte b3). It's not hard to convert ints to byte[] either if you need to send ints and stuff like that.

Comment: But that's what datainputstream and dataoutputstream do. So I could just extendier them. Because I can't extendier eh streaming from the socket. I can just warp them.

Comment: You can do that too, it's just a matter of how clean and efficient you want your code. I have made a similar thing that you are doing.  I just made a class that keeps an instance of a InputStream in it and uses the write methodist write bytes and methods visible methods to convert the types I want to send to bytes. Anyways, good luck :)

Comment: What you described is exactly what dataoutputstream does. It keeps the outputstream instance and calls its Write method.